# Need help replacing a specificUnknown "P Address" in XML with Python

Tags: python, xml

I built a script that configures some files in Python but got stuck with replacing an IP address if it is unknown (F.E if someone changed it)
The line looks something like this:

except that localhost can be changed to any IP (For Example- 2.2.2.2)
and I need to find it and replace it with my new IP address.
What I got so far is this:

```
file = open('*Path*').read()
file = file.replace('*Old string with localhost IP*',
                '*New string with my IP*')
```

but it can only replace a known string, any one have an idea on how can I do that?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: not quite sure what you are asking, but a regex may serve you well